# Raw Pixel Data to the PNG or drawing Raw Pixel Data

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, png

```
this.terrain = new jaws.Sprite({ x: 0, y: 0, image: this.currentLevel.terrainImage, scale_image: 6 });
var rawTerrain = this.terrain.asCanvasContext();
this.rawPixelData = rawTerrain.getImageData(0, 0, this.terrain.width, this.terrain.height).data;
```

That is my code to create a new map on my HTML5 game. I'm a using a .png map. I also extract its raw pixel data so that I can read the map for collisions and other stuff.

I wanted to implement grenades and these grenades would actually change the map. I can't change the .png. How do you suggest I go about doing this without moving to another kind of map loading (I want to keep using .png maps)?

My idea was to manipulate the raw pixel data (very doable) and then draw it, but I have no idea of how I can do it. Could I convert the raw pixel data to a .png and then draw it?

I looked for libpng with Javascript and I found pnglets, but I think that remaking the png will take a long time and it would just freeze the game a lot.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `canvas`'s `putImageData` method to draw the raw data onto a canvas:

```
this.terrain = new jaws.Sprite({ 
    x: 0, 
    y: 0, 
    image: this.currentLevel.terrainImage, 
    scale_image: 6 
});
var rawTerrain = this.terrain.asCanvasContext();
this.rawPixelData = rawTerrain.getImageData(
    0, 0, this.terrain.width, this.terrain.height
).data;

// modify the pixel data and return updated data..
var modifiedPixelData = modifyPixelData(rawTerrain.getImageData(
    0, 0, this.terrain.width, this.terrain.height
));
// Put the data back into the canvas.
rawTerrain.putImageData(modifiedPixelData, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Using that code, I am drawing the modified pixel data to rawTerrain, but I actually need it on terrain, which is what I effectively draw to the screen. Can I draw rawTerrain or do I have to convert rawTerrain to a new terrain somehow? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure of the details behind jaws, but I would think that the `.asCanvasContext()` method would return a reference to the canvas context used by the sprite.