# Get pixel data of a png without drawing it on a canvas

Tags: javascript, png

I'm using javascript to program a simple web game, it works by drawing the png map on a html canvas where the colors on the map are coded as a game object (black is a wall, red is a spike).

I wanted to detect the color of the pixel the player goes to, but the problem is that every computer processes the png image in a slightly different way based on its settings (at least that's what I understood).

Can I, instead of checking the color drawn on the canvas, get the color of the pixel of the actual png image (so that's the same on every machine)? Do I have to use raw pixel data? If yes, how does that work?

Also, should [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921880/raw-pixel-data-to-the-png-or-drawing-raw-pixel-data) help me? (I tried to understand that but I couldn't)

I'm not sure that's possible to do with javascript, but maybe with php or something else.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Without a canvas you would have to use a client side PNG library to get the pixel data. Also, the RGB values of the pixels are not dependent on the computer's color profile or whatever, a PNG might not look the same on every monitor / screen, but the RGB values will definitely be the same on every machine. Also, yes, you can use PHP instead. Or simply don't use a PNG to store your map data.

Comment: @ChrisG no, a PNG image may not be drawn on a canvas the same on every computer, yes the color profile of the browser and more importantly the ones defined by the image will come to play. To OP, how many different kind of objects should your map contain? Using only "web-safe" colors in a sRGB png should be "fine". But if you only have a few types (<255), then storing each object as an Uint8 might be a better idea. It may take a bit more space than a compressed image but that would probably be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: If the PNG file is a safe asset, it can be Javascript, but it will be possible if you receive the PNG as a `File` object, transform it into `Arraybuffer`, and analyze the PNG binary. I have experience making 2bit Bitmap encoder and decoder in the same way. I'll answer when I have time.

Comment: @Kaiido I was talking about the RGB values stored inside the PNG file, viewing it as another reason to process the file directly instead of drawing it onto a canvas first. Should've phrased that better.

Comment: Yeah, but how do i process an image with JavaScript without drawing it on a canvas? I plan to have only a few object types

Comment: @Kaiido I didn't know the existence of "web safe" colors, I googled them up, tried to used them but that doesn't seem to solve the issue. Also, what do you mean by "Storing each object as an Uint8"?

Comment: I mean `const arr=new Uint8Array(width * height); arr[x] = aValueBetween0and255` then you save that ArrayBuffer as a binary file (`new Blob([arr])`) you save that on your server and your client simply `fetch(theFileURL).then(resp=>resp.arrayBuffer()).then(buf=>{ const map = new Uint8Array(buf);...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're making a game, I wonder why you're trying to detect the color. Are you going to use your image as a map editor? Most image files are slow, heavy, and have to go through decoding.
I think you're going to use the image file as a map because it's convenient to create, but I think it's more efficient to using the vector object for use in games. For example, SVG files are easy to make and you can use them separately in the way you think. Instead of using a file with a known extension, you can create your own object and object editor separately.

Anyway, as I left a comment, I found the library you need. It is a library that can decode PNG files on the browser, which reads the binary of the PNG file and returns the byte analysis result to the object. You can check pixel information in the data field and decoding takes a considerable amount of time.

```
import UPNG from "upng-js";

const input = document.getElementById("upload") as HTMLInputElement;

input.onchange = async (ev) => {
  const file = input.files?.[0];
  if (!file) return;
  if (file.type !== "image/png") return;
  const result = UPNG.decode(await file.arrayBuffer());
  console.log(result);
};
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/upng-example-qg6yvp?file=/src/index.ts)

You can find these libraries, view the [PNG binary structure](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html) and implement them yourself, but I don't recommend them because I think it will be a very tiring task. Anyway, it is also possible to read and write files through `Blob` and `Arraybuffer` in the browser.

Comment: Okay i don't fully understand the mechanics of base64 encoding and blobs, but after some research i think i see what you mean, that is too slow. Yes, I am using a png as a map editor, I know that's not the best idea but i wanted to do something quick, I will definitely try out vectors and figure that out. Thanks!